# Organizing test hierarchy in clojure project

Tags: testing, clojure

There are two directories in a clojure project - src/ and test/.
There's a file my_methods.clj in the src/calc/ directory which starts with

`(ns calc.my_methods...)`.

I want to create a test file for it in test directory - test/my_methods-test.clj

```
(ns test.my_methods-test
  (:require [calc.my_methods])
  (:use clojure.test))
```

In the $CLASSPATH there are both project root directory and src/ directory. But the exception is still

"Could not locate calc/my_methods__init.class or calc/my_methods.clj on classpath". What is the problem with requiring it in the test file?

`echo $CLASSPATH` gives this:

```
~/project:~/project/src
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I'd suggest using [Leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) to manage the `CLASSPATH` for you. Second, I find that the `~` character to stand in for my home directory never works in the `CLASSPATH` context - I have to specify the absolute path, no aliasing (e.g. `/Users/colin/path/to/project`). Third, it's conventional to have `src` and `test` on the classpath, but not the root level of a project.

Comment: +1 for suggesting leiningen. It's the de facto standard build/run/pacakage tool for Clojure and it'll make your life a million times simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Be very careful about your use of dashes and underscores in file names and namespaces. If you don't get the naming conventions right, this can be the source of a lot of confusion. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223369/32174, point 2. And as @trptcolin mentions, use Leiningen.