# lein project naming guidelines

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I would like a pointer to the proper way to name a project when invoking

`lein new <projectname>`

My question is related to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718658/why-does-java-complain-that-namespace-is-not-found) I've asked recently.

Specifically, a lot of projects I have seen use dashes, like clojure-csv.
Yet, I am having trouble getting a project to work on Windows.

So my specific question is is there a way to create the project when invoking `lein new` and what other adjustments in project.clj and core.clj should I expect to make when creating a Clojure project on Windows (in my case Windows 7) using lein?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take inspiration form search into `clojars.org` like https://clojars.org/search?q=the.

The pattern seems to be `namespace/name-with-dashes` or `name-with-dashes`. For instance :

```
 cool-stuff
 stackoverflow/cool-stuff
 com.stackoverflow/cool-stuff
```

The recommended way to name namespaces is with a reverse domain like `com.stackoverflow.subsection`.

Comment: Ok, so why is there a problem with my having dashes in the my namespace, directory-name, and so on? Refer to link in my OP.

Comment: Try `lein new name-with-dashes` and writing files like https://gist.github.com/3839051. It is perfectly working and display `Hello` after `lein run`

Answer (score 1):

There is an "official"* **ban on further projects who's name is a pun on the word Clojure**... Please, this has to stop ;-) Specifically project names of the form verb+jure

- so if your project does foo please do not name it foojure

existing projects like compojure (compose+jure) are cool because they predate this collective intention.

*not in any way official ;-)

Comment: Arthur Ulfeldt If dashes are OK, then why are they not (or seem not to be) OK on Windows?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus, there's nothing wrong with dashes in Windows. Maybe you're trying to use filenames that match your namespace names? You can't do that for Clojure on any platform -- the filenames need to use underscores  where the namespace names use dashes.